# Unable to send UDP packets to local port with python, fails checksum according to WireShark

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp, socks

I've been pulling my hair out over this one. I'm trying to write a SOCKS5 server in Python to tunnel UDP traffic. I bind to a port, and receive data fine. I then parse the SOCKS5 UDP header (not the typical UDP header), and forward the datagram to the requested endpoint.

All is good. I then listen for a response from the endpoint (resending if timeout), and get a response. Great!

Here is where I'm losing my mind-

I get the datagram back from the endpoint. I re-encapsulate the returned datagram according to the [SOCKS5 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1928), which is the same UDP header as before, except I have now changed the destination address and port to the original caller. I use:

```
sock_client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                            socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock_client.sendto(packed_datagram, (self.client_ip, self.client_port))
```

to send the datagram back to client. The client never receives the reply! Ever!

Looking at WireShark, it says this: Header checksum: 0x0000 [incorrect, should be 0xcd1f (may be caused by "IP checksum offload"?)]

Shouldn't the python socket implementation, with socket.DGRAM set, automatically pack my data correctly in a UDP header and calculate the appropriate checksum? Why is it being set to 0x0000? I checked the payload in hex, the checksum is indeed set wrong. What the heck is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not following two pieces of the SOCKS5 spec accurately.

> A UDP association terminates when the TCP connection that the UDP
>   ASSOCIATE request arrived on terminates.

I was terminating the TCP socket immediately after completing UDP relay handshake. TCP must stay open until the back-and-forth is finished.

> When    a UDP relay server receives a reply datagram from a remote
>   host, it    MUST encapsulate that datagram using the above UDP request
>   header,    and any authentication-method-dependent encapsulation.

I was using the client's IP and port as the values in the datagram. It needs to be the remote server's IP and port, essentially the UDP header encapsulation is a clone of what the client passed in.

With these two issues solved, the SOCKS5 server works as anticipated.

Answer (score 1):

The checksum calculation is done by the drivers in the operating system. In may cases, the calculation is done by the network card itself. IIRC, Wireshark grabs local packets just before they are handed off to the network stack. It's common to checksum errors for all locally generated packets.

Comment: That makes sense, but means I truly have no idea why the local host isn't receiving my udp packets. Does it matter if I send them from a thread? I'm really grasping for straws here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your part of code correctly you create a new socket to send the data back to the client. Thus this will be a new socket with a random source IP, e.g. from the view of the client you have the following packet flow:

```
client_ip:client_port  -> socks5_ip:socks_port
client_ip:client_port  <- socks5_ip:random_port
```

The client has probably a connected socket to the socks5 server and thus expects replies coming from socks5_ip:socks_port, not the random_port.
So you should not create a new socket to the client but instead reply using the existing socket where you received the data from the client.

Comment: It shouldn't matter, because UDP sockets can be envisioned like holes rather than pipes. No matter the source of the data, once the data is shoved in the hole, it is delivered (UDP is connectionless, unlike TCP). That being said, I reused the same socket that data was received on as you suggested, and still no luck. On the suggestion of a colleague, I also tried binding the SOCKS5 server and the UDP relay server to my local IP on the network rather than 127.0.0.1 and setting the client to connect to it via the local IP. Still no luck :(

Comment: Please provide a tcpdump of the connection between client and socks server.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I solved my issue in the answered question.

Answer (score 0):

turn off tx-checksumming using the linux command:

```
ethtool -K eth0 tx off
```

OR use this function to calculate the checksum

```
def checksum(data):
    s = 0
    n = len(data) % 2
    for i in range(0, len(data)-n, 2):
        s+= ord(data[i]) + (ord(data[i+1]) << 8)
    if n:
        s+= ord(data[i+1])
    while (s >> 16):
        s = (s & 0xFFFF) + (s >> 16)
    s = ~s & 0xffff
    return s
```

Where the data is the pseudo header